# Sharepoint Framework/PnP-JS/React : state Object doesnt work

Tags: sharepoint-framework, typescript, pnp-js-core, react

I have created a property (age) in the state Object. However, I can not access this property in my code. I am getting an Error Message:

> Property 'age' does not exist on type '{}

Here below is my code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReactPnP.module.scss';
import myStyles from './myStyle.module.scss';
import { IReactPnPProps } from './IReactPnPProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";


interface ISPVehicule {
  Title: string;
  Marque: string;
  Modele: string;
  Vitesse: string;
  Poid: string;
}


export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, {}> {

  private vehiculeList:  ISPVehicule[];
  private web;

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = { age: 0};
    this.web = new Web(this.props.contextUrl);

    var initialAge = this.state.age;
  ...
```

Do you know I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your code tell the TypeScript that the state object is empty object with no members. `React.Component` accepts two generic types - properties object and  state object. You have to change this line

```
export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, {}> {
```

to

```
export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, any> {
```

or to some specific object like

```
interface IState {
  age: number;
}

export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, IState> {
```